# Reusing the file definition of one file for another with out opening /closing it

Tags: cobol

Reusing the file definition of file1  for another i.e file2 with out opening /closing file1.

I have a monthly file and my requirement is generate a daily file similar to monthly file.The record length and the File definition of both the files are same.

Can i make use of monthly file's FD to hold data and do some validation using monthly file data items for my Daily file and write my daily file later?
lot of validations are being done using monthly file's FD variables and I cannot do same validations using daily file's variables as i  need to make changes/rewrite lot of code  in many places in multiple programs.

Note: I am doing my daily file processing & generation after the monthly processing is over at the end .
Also ,we are using  UNIX environment.

Please suggest me  how can i achieve this if above mentioned method is not possible.

Comment: You've said that you are in a `UNIX` environment but you haven't specified your compiler.
Furthermore it is not 100% clear to me what you actually ask for...
In general: some compilers only assign actual storage to the `FD` variables after a working `OPEN`, but after this is done you can place anything into the variables, as long as you "save+restore" the old content or are sure that no `[RE]WRITE` is done on the file without putting the "correct" data there directly before.

Comment: I am using progeni compiler.My requirement is  just to generate daily file instead of monthly file.All validation that we do for monthly needs to be done on daily basis.Since I need to do processing on daily basis ,I want to  hold my daily data in monthly file FD nd use it as work varibales and do validation using monthly FD variables and move the data back to my daily file for writing.

Comment: Why not put the record layout in working storage and just move it to whatever file you need to use? It seems like you may be over complicating this

Comment: Not enough information here to give you exactly what you want, but why not simply change the file name before you open the file?  That is, since the FD and record layout is identical, either copy the FD and record layout to new copy files, then change the destination?

Comment: The web says progeni is a COBOL editor, not a compiler...

Answer (score 0):

The record area for a file is not available until the file is opened. The `SAME RECORD AREA` clause may be used to provide an alias.

```
   identification division.
   program-id. srac.
   environment division.
   input-output section.
   file-control.
       select optional monthly-file assign "monthly.dat"
           file status monthly-stat.
       select daily-file assign "daily.dat"
           file status daily-stat.
   i-o-control.
       same record area monthly-file daily-file.
   data division.
   file section.
   fd monthly-file.
   1 monthly-id pic 999.
   fd daily-file.
   1 daily-id pic 999.
   working-storage section.
   1 monthly-stat pic x(2).
   1 daily-stat pic x(2).
   procedure division.
       open input monthly-file daily-file
       display "monthly-stat:" space monthly-stat
       display "daily-stat:  " space daily-stat
       read daily-file
       display "monthly-id:" space monthly-id
       if monthly-id < 10
           add 100 to monthly-id
       end-if
       display "daily-id:  " space daily-id
       close monthly-file daily-file
       stop run
       .

monthly-stat: 05
daily-stat:   00
monthly-id: 001
daily-id:   101
```

In this example, the monthly and daily files have identical record description entries; but, the monthly file does not exist. Yet, one may use the data-names for the monthly file for validation, modification, or whatever.